# Tensorflow - dimensions of data, placeholder

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am a complete beginner in Tensorflow, and I apologize if my question is trivial, but I have looked into both the documentation and Google and I couldn't find the answer. (I also apologize for my english)

I'd like to do something like

```
sess.run(train, {x:x_train, y:x_train}
```

where x_train is an array of size 3190 containing my input data (arrays of dimension 60*4)

My question is, should x be :

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [60,4])
```

or

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [None,60,4])
```

?

The first one gives the following error :

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (3190, 60, 4) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(60, 4)'
```

and if I use the second one, how can I reach x[i][j] with 0<=i<60 and 0<=j<4 if I want to compute for example

```
tf.logical_and(x[i1][j1],x[i2][j2])
```

?

Thanking you in advance for your answer.

Comment: You do need a 3D tensor in this case. However, the example `tf.logical_and(x[i1][j1],x[i2][j2])` is not clear enough. What is the relationship between `i1, j1` and `i2, j2`? Do you intend to calculate a `60 * 4 * 60 * 4` 4D tensor?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Each of my 3190 inputs is a 60*4 tensor which represents a DNA sequence of 60 nucleotides. Each nucleotide is represented as a 1*4 array of booleans indicating whether the nucleotide is A, C, G or T (for example x[30] = [1,0,0,0] if there is an A at position 30). I would like to perform some "AND" operations on the inputs, for example "there is an A at position 3 AND there is a C at position 15" (x[3][0] AND x[15][1]). So each would be a 1*1 tensor.
I hope this is clearer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do use

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [None,60,4])
```

and for your **logical and** use

```
x_flat = tf.reshape( x , [ -1 , 60*4 ] )
ij1 = tf.reshape( tf.one_hot( [i1*4+j1] , 60*4 , dtype=tf.float32 ) , [ 60*4 , 1 ] )
ij2 = tf.reshape( tf.one_hot( [i2*4+j2] , 60*4 , dtype=tf.float32 ) , [ 60*4 , 1 ] )

tf.logical_and( tf.matmul( x_flat , ij1 ) , tf.matmul( x_flat , ij2 ) )
```

Comment: Thanks ! I added a few casts (bool to float32 for matmul and float32 to bool for logical_and) and this seems to be working. Thank you very much !

Comment: Please mark this answer as the solution @DNAprototype